# Angular debug in VS Code - Breakpoints unbound

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my Ionic/Angular project in VS Code, but once I start the debuging mode, all my breakpoints turn grey and become unbound.

This is my launch.json:

```
{
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8100",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

My Angular version is 13.2.3 and my Node version is 16.14.2.

I have set souceMap to true in the angular.json file and tried tweaking the setting, but nothing really worked.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

VS code team provides a set of instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI)

basically, you can configure/create your `launch.json` similar to this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
        "/*": "*",
        "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ng e2e",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/e2e/protractor.conf.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and `tasks.json` to this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "start",
      "isBackground": true,
      "presentation": {
        "focus": true,
        "panel": "dedicated"
      },
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": {
        "owner": "typescript",
        "source": "ts",
        "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
        "fileLocation": [
          "relative",
          "${cwd}"
        ],
        "pattern": "$tsc",
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": {
            "regexp": "(.*?)"
          },
          "endsPattern": {
            "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
          }
        }
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

And you can just press F5!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple projects in your workSpaceDirectory?
If so, you have to add this in your path. E.g.:

```
"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/YOURPROJECT1"
```

Use slash `/`if you are on windows.

Answer (score 0):

My issue:

- My Angular: 14.x
- Node.js => 18.x  => not support, can't debug
- Downgrade to 16.x => work perfect

Answer (score 0):

This works for me if the error in the debug console is something like ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1

Change the start script in package.json to

`ng serve --host 127.0.0.1`

The vs code js debugger seems to look for the web app specifically on the host address 127.0.0.1 and angular serves it on localhost by default. I guess there is a difference between them.

For launch.json I've also found the "launch" request type to be unreliable. Try using the "attach" chrome launch configuration instead and remove preLaunchTask. You'll need to look up how to start chrome with remote debugging enabled.